# Bash Script does not exit when run in parallel

Tags: bash

I am trying to run a few scripts in parallel which works, but the bash script does not exit even I use exit command.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -uo pipefail

./create_net.sh &
./start_process1.sh &
./start_process2.sh &
exit
```

Comment: `does not exist` "exist" or "exits"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the '&' to run it in the background will do the trick but also add a 'wait' before exit. The bash 'wait' will also come in handy. Refer also to this : https://www.golinuxcloud.com/run-shell-scripts-in-parallel-collect-exit-status-process/